# postgreSQL is running slow

Tags: linux, postgresql

I have a DWH server running on postgreSQL.TheJenkins is also installed in the same server.

For the few weeks the server was not running fine,The data visualization tool has loading issues,All Jenkins job is running much slower.

So can anyone please guide me how to troubleshoot the issue and make the server faster.

Is there a open source monitoring tool,help to find the root cause of slowness.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you have to find the problematic queries.

This is done by installing [`pg_stat_statements`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/pgstatstatements.html).

After a while, you can query the `pg_stat_statements` view to find the statements with the highest `total_time`. These are the statements that consume most of your database time.

If you are looking for long running statements, you can also set `log_min_duration_statement` to lig long running queries.

Once you have found the problem statement, run it with `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)`. That will tell you what the problem is.

If you have trouble interpreting the data, ask a question here.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the comment! I will definitely try this out.Also i would like to find which all are the indices are missing in my PostgreSQL database and i tried to create this extension "   CREATE EXTENSION pg_qualstats;"but it is showing the below error.   ERROR:  could not open extension control file "/usr/share/postgresql/11/extension/pg_qualstats.control": No such file or directory
SQL state: 58P01

Comment: Any suggestions on this please?

Comment: That extension is not part of the PostgreSQL software distribution. You'll have do download, build and install it.